# How to update the Json content attributes such as array and other sub level items?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

**My Objective:** To update array attribute and other sub json attribute programatically.

**Environment:** Visual Studio C#, NewtonSoft Library

I have a json file sample as below

```
{
    "model": "xx.yyy",
    "make": "philips",  
    "alias": [ "abc", "bcd", "aee", "sample" ],
    "variables": {
        "temperature": {
            "dataType": "number",
            "unit": {
                "value": "°C",
                "enum": [ "°C", "°F" ]
            },
            "min": -50,
            "max": 300,
            "description": "The skin temperature measured outside of the motor."
        }
    }
}
```

I am loading the json file content as below

```
var jsonContent = File.ReadAllText(@"\path\example.json");
```

I want to update **alias** attribute as below

First I parse the data as below to convert into an object

```
var dataObj = JObject.Parse(jsonContent);
```

From here I could able to update the root level properties as below.

```
dataObj.Root["make"].Replace("siemens");
```

I am not sure how to update the ***alias*** attribute and ***datatype*** attribute under *variable*. I want it as below

```
"alias": [ "abc", "bcd", "aee", "discard" ]
"datatype": "string"
```

As a crude way I tried replacing the values as below after serializing it.

```
var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataObj);
serializedData.Replace("sample", "discard");
```

That too did not work. Any help.

> Note: I wish to see the solution without associating to class object

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, there is a missing comma `,` after `"alias": [ "abc", "bcd", "aee", "sample" ]` and there should be an extra closing brace `}` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for that. Updated now. @phuzi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For string array attribute **alias** I have achieved as below

```
var aliasNew = new string[] { "abc", "bcd", "aee", "discard"};
var aliasSer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aliasNew);
dataObj.Root["alias"].Replace[aliasSer]
```

For variable attribute part I have achieved as below

```
dataObj.Root["variables"]["temperature"]["dataType"].Replace("string");
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. I used this json and deserialized it into a class object. Once you have a class object, you can play with it and update whataver you want to.

JSON :

```
{
   "model": "xx.yyy",
  "make": "philips",  
  "alias": [ "abc", "bcd", "aee", "sample" ],
"variables": {
"temperature": {
  "dataType": "number",
  "unit": {
    "value": "°C",
    "enum": [ "°C", "°F" ]
  },
  "min": -50,
  "max": 300,
  "description": "The skin temperature measured outside of the motor."
    }
}
}
```

C# classes :

```
public class Unit
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public List<string> @enum { get; set; }
    }

    public class Temperature
    {
        public string dataType { get; set; }
        public Unit unit { get; set; }
        public int min { get; set; }
        public int max { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Variables
    {
        public Temperature temperature { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string model { get; set; }
        public string make { get; set; }
        public List<string> alias { get; set; }
        public Variables variables { get; set; }
    }
```

C# Code:

```
var jsonContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\kanaka\Desktop\sample.json");
var serializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonContent);
var q = serializedData.variables.temperature.unit.@enum; // update whatever you want to, serialize again
```

Now you can update the class object values to whatever you want to. Once updated, serialize it again. It will be more maintainable and easy if you deserialize it to a class object

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. But currently I am not inclined towards creating a class structure replicating the Json, since I have many types of Json files in my repository to work with. Each one I can't create class..